# how to give access to view only one database to a particular users in sql server 2008

Tags: view

I need to give 5 different users to access one database, hiding other databases.

I have tired to give access, i am able to give only one user not for all.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you tried? Also, what error messages did you get? I know very little about SQL Server, but this is the 101 of access/security.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1:

If you want users to View only,

```
USE <database name here>
GO 
GRANT VIEW Definition TO User1

USE <database name here>
GO 
GRANT VIEW Definition TO User2
```

and so on for all 5 of them

Method 2:

If you meant to give them read only access

Step 1:

In case for domain account users, create a login from windows account with below( for the users you want to give access to say Database A):

```
CREATE LOGIN [<domainName>\<login_name>] FROM WINDOWS;
GO
```

Else (in case not windows account)

```
 CREATE LOGIN <login_name> WITH PASSWORD = '<enterStrongPasswordHere>';
GO
```

Step 2: Perform below for all 5 users to grant login permission to access the database in question

Say for user 1:

```
 USE (your database name)
 CREATE USER (username1) FOR LOGIN (login name)
```

Similarly for user 2

```
USE (your database name)
 CREATE USER (username2) FOR LOGIN (login name)
```

and so on for all 5..

Step 3: Once you have users added in your database, you can give them any rights you want, e.g. you could assign it the db_datareader database role to read all tables.

```
USE (your database)
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', '(username1)'
```

.... for all 5